# カスタムプロトコル(iOSでいうところのURLスキーム)のMacでの動作について疑問

Tags: macos

カスタムプロトコルにアクセスすると関連付けられたアプリが起動する機能、この機能の正式な呼び方を知りませんがiOSでいうところの(カスタム)URLスキームの機能の動作ですが、Windowsの場合、独自のプロトコル及び起動するアプリをレジストリに登録することで使用可能となりますが、Macの場合は、必要事項を記述したinfo.plistを用意すればできるということを知りました。

そこで疑問に思ったのが、Macの場合、Windowsのような"登録"という手順を経ていません。カスタムプロトコルにアクセスされたとき、マシン内にあるすべてのアプリのinfo.plistを調べているのでしょうか？

追記
私は、Electronでアプリを開発しており、electron-packagerで実行ファイルを生成しています(dmgファイルではありません)。dmgファイルなどからのインストールやアプリケーションフォルダに入れるということは行わず、生成された実行ファイル(xxx.appフォルダ)をMacの適当な場所(アプリケーションフォルダ以外の場所)にコピーして試してみたら、ちゃんと認識し起動することができました。インストールなどの特別な作業を行わずにコピーするだけで認識してくれたというところに疑問を持った次第です。

Comment: `"登録"の手順を経ていない`とは、何を見てそう思ったのでしょうか？MacのOS内部までは詳しくないですが、アプリケーションフォルダに入れる、またはインストール、開発中アプリを起動する、などで`/Library/Application Support/`に`Info.plist`など文字通りアプリを補助するファイルが保存されておりますが、そのタイミングが分からないと言うことでしょうか？

Comment: 何が疑問か分かりませんが、こちらとか参考になりませんか？　http://www.forensicfocus.com/apple-mac-os-x-property-list　もし自己解決した場合は納得した内容を自己回答ください。

Comment: Myakuさん
コメントありがとうございます。
質問文に疑問を持った具体的内容を追記させていただきました。